# Python refer to class from within class

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I've become aware of `@staticmethod` - next question, are you supposed to use the class name to refer to these methods from within the class?

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def imstatic():
        print("i'm static")

    @staticmethod
    def anotherstatic():
        # Is this the proper python way?
        C.imstatic()

    @staticmethod
    def brokenstatic():
        # This doesn't work..
        self.imstatic()
```

Comment: Did you try this?  The answer should be pretty self evident, but yes.

Comment: Well the reason I asked is because Java and PHP which I'm used to both have keywords for this...

Comment: Note that Python's static method is a different beast from Java and PHP static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you don't have any other reference to the class from within a static method. You could make these **class methods** instead, using the [`classmethod` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def imstatic():
        print("i'm static")

    @classmethod
    def anotherstatic(cls):
        cls.imstatic()
```

A class method **does** have a reference to the class.

Comment: Thanks, I believe `@classmethod` is what I'm after. I've now found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) and will keep reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to refer to the class within a static method you should probably be using a [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) instead:

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def imstatic():
        print("i'm static")

    @classmethod
    def imclass(cls):
        cls.imstatic()
```

In the same way that instance methods are "magically" given a reference to the instance as the first argument, class methods are given a reference to the class.  You can call them either from an instance or from the class directly, for example both of the following are valid and have the same behavior:

```
C().imclass()
C.imclass()
```

That being said, if you do still want to use a static method your current approach is correct, just refer to the class by name.

Comment: Also, `self` is only used for instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to call the static method of that specific class, yes, you must specify it by name. If you want to support overriding the static methods, what you want is a classmethod instead: it passes the *class* on which the method is being called as the first parameter, analogous to `self` on regular instance methods, so you can call the overridden method. In general I'd suggest using classmethods.